# Analysis of substances

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

The crystalline substance X completely decomposed without the formation of a dry
residue when heated. As a result of adding a solution of calcium hydroxide to the
solution of substance X, a precipitate insoluble in water fell out. Substance X is: A

- ammonium carbonate, B - sodium sulfite, B - ammonium chloride, G - sodium
  hydrogen carbonate.
  Explain your answer.